# How to transform double to IEEE754 format?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, double, ieee-754

The function should return a string representation of a double type number in the IEEE754 format

```
public class GetIEEE754FormatAdapter : ITransformer<double, string>
    {     
        public string Transform(double obj)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(obj));
        }
    }
```

For example if obj is 122.625, the result should be a string 0100000001011110101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

My implementation is returning wrong result

Comment: You are looking for a binary representation of a 64-bit IEEE number, right?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thank you it's right, but how I can remove the first bit from the left? The string is one bit longer than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the  trick:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(BinaryString(122.625));
        // 00000001011110101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    }

    static string BinaryString(double value)
    {
        long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value);
        return Convert.ToString(bits, 2).Substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's right, but how I can remove the first bit from the left? The string is one bit longer than expected

Comment: That is the sign bit. it is part of the IEEE standard. I edited the post by removing the fist character in the answer.

Comment: @Kurbanov27 - correction, the first bit is the sign bit of the exponent, as the exponent vaue is biased by 1023. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/ieee-floating-point-representation?view=msvc-170

Comment: @JohnAlexiou that's incorrect. The  notation on that page  is misleading (kind of copy paste without copying proper definition), but text is correct. First bit is sign bit of significand value, followed by 11(!) bits of exponent. 11 bit would get you 1023 and a sign.As a proof, `-122.625` gets you `100000001011110101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`